# Should Theoretical Computer Science SE and mathoverflow be merged?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-recommendation, stackexchange-2.0, site-proposal

Now that [mathoverflow.net](http://mathoverflow.net) is a part of the formal Stack Exchange network, do you think that [Theoretical Computer Science SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) should be merged into it? TCS, after all, is just another branch of mathematics. And both are targeting professionals and post-graduate level students.

Having a separate TCS SE site independent of mathoverflow is akin to having a Java programming site, when we already have StackOverflow. Not good.

Comment: That is interesting, but I would say that Theoretical Computer Science is *both* a branch of Mathematics and a branch of Computer Science, with a bias for the latter. So I would suggest incorporate it in *Computer Science SE* instead...

Comment: @Boris [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Yannis I should have checked before, thx ;-) (previous comment edited)

Comment: You might want to propose this idea on the Mathoverflow Meta and see what the response is...I have a hunch that the idea won't be warmly welcomed. It made me [think of this though](http://xkcd.com/435/) :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The MO people don't really visit here much, as they only recently came into the SE network. This is really something the communities of those sites have to decide. So you're in the wrong place to propose this.

That said, computer science and mathematics are strongly related, but still different subjects. I see no reason to mess with currently working sites by trying to merge them. The scope of each site is much more determined by existing communities and what they want than any abstract organization concept SE would create. The mathematicians seem happy with their site, and the computer scientists as well.

Answer (score 9):

Well, there's a separate TeX and LaTeX SE, even though both are eminently programming languages and some small minority of what people do in LaTeX feels like programming.  You'll find that the nature of the questions asked there is markedly different from what you'd expect on SO.

Similarly, you find a certain kind of question on TCS (mostly about CS theory), a very different kind of question on mathoverflow ("real math", for lack of a better term), and yet another different kind of question on the computational science stackexchange (lots of numerical PDEs, some numerical other things.)  There doesn't seem to be all that much overlap between the three sites.